# Firebird db connection string

Tags: c#, firebird2.5

When i run the c# code  with firebird db as backend it shows.My code is plain and simple then why is it showing such an error??

An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll

Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString =
                                    "User=SYSDBA;" +
                                    "Password=masterkey;" +
                                    "Database=TESTFB.fdb;" +
                                    "DataSource=localhost;" +
                                    "Port=3050;" +
                                    "Dialect=3;" +
                                    "Charset=NONE;" +
                                    "Role=;" +
                                    "Connection lifetime=15;" +
                                    "Pooling=true;" +
                                    "MinPoolSize=0;" +
                                    "MaxPoolSize=50;" +
                                    "Packet Size=8192;" +
                                    "ServerType=1;";
        //string sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT(ID,NAME) VALUES(@ID,@NAME)";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE ID=@ID AND NAME=@NAME;";
        try
        {
            FbConnection con = new FbConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", FbDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (FbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("5--" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with your code.  The issue is with the DLL you're referencing. You could be using the wrong version, or using a 32 bit version on a 64 bit machine, etc.

Comment: you mean to say that firebird ado.net data provider DLL could be the wrong one??

Comment: Yes, per the error message.  The BadImageFormatException means it can't read the DLL for some reason.

Comment: @Tim thanks a lot.Changed platform target to x64 and its working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use embedded (`ServerType=1`), but the `fbembed.dll` (or `fbclient.dll`) on your path does not match the runtime bitness (eg 32 bit vs 64 bit).

Are you sure you want to use Firebird embedded? The rest of the configuration string seems to suggest you want to connect to a normal Firebird server, in which case `ServerType=0` (or just leaving it off) is better as then you don't have a dependency on a native dll.